# Problem with connect to azure VM from MacOs

Tags: linux, macos, azure

The Linux virtual machine on Azure, the problem encountered, can not connect through rdp (Microsoft Remote Desktop). Throws a connection error, respectively. I use MacOs (I tried it with Windows, the same problem).

The question is what could be the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no Microsoft RDP for Linux.  You have to connect via SSH on 22.

If you have diagnostics enabled on the Linux VM, you can use the serial console.  Just click on the VM in the Azure Portal -> Serial Console.

If you really want to connect via RDP, then you can try installing xrdp on your VM, but it really depends what flavor of Linux you have deployed.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo service xrdp start
```

Don't forget you need access to TCP port 3389.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still finding my feet :)